# dynamic inputs through jquery and submit to mysql table

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, input

I need some advice in the following code.

```
var count = 1;
$(function(){
    $('#addmore').click(function(){
        count += 1;
        $('ul').append("<li><input type='text' id='hd"+count+"' name='hd"+count+"' value='heading' onClick='this.select();'> <input type='text' id='amount"+count+"' name='amount"+count+"' value='amount' onClick='this.select();'></li>");
//      return false;
    });
});
```

what exact php code should i use to submit all the input into my test table of mysql.

```
<button id="addmore">+</button>
<form id="myForm" name="myForm" action="" method="post" onSubmit="return false;">
<ul>
    <li><input type="text" id="hd1" name="hd1" value="heading" onClick="this.select();">
    <input type="text" id="amount1" name="amount1" value="amount" onClick="this.select();"></li>
</ul>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submit" name="submit">
</form>

<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

echo "h";
};
?>
```

keeping in mind that i've test table with two fields 'heading' and 'amount'.

---

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    foreach($_POST['hd'] as $hds){
        echo $hds;
        mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO test (hdg) VALUES ($hds)");
    };
};
```

and its not adding data into my table

Comment: This is a bit ambiguous - the PHP script that puts data into the table doesn't need to care about your JS function, it can just check to see what data it is given. But to give "exact php code" you would need to tell us something about your MySQL table's structure. Also remember that you can see if a form value is set with something like isset($_POST['hd1']).

Comment: What have you tried? Can you post your php code that you have so far? What are you using for your database connection - `mysqli` or `PDO`?

Comment: my mysql table structure is simple
Id(int), hdg(varchar), amt(varchar) and table name is test.

Comment: JSON.stringify the values and send them to php. There run a loop for each set of value and insert into the db

Comment: // Create connection
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","transport");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno($con)){
 echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

Comment: Amir... i want to add a record of expenses into a field of mysql table. adding dynamically inputs and upon submitting all record goes to a particular field.

Comment: Haunt... what exact php code to loop and insert into database

Comment: Sean... i have placed the database connection... it working perfectly all i need to add my multiple inputs into field of table. there are two fields in my test table. one get name of expense and other get its amount. like fuel expense amount 300, food - 100, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `[]` for the `name` attributes instead of the numbers:

```
<li><input type="text" id="hd1" name="hd[]" value="heading" onClick="this.select();">
```

On the server-side you will have an array of values.

```
$hd = $_POST['hd']; // Returns an array
```

Comment: if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
$hd = $_POST['hd'];
echo $hd;
};